# Attribute ‘set’ object has no attribute ‘data’

Tags: python, urllib, attributeerror

I’m running Python 3.9 and urllib. It’s meant to source the HTML from a website but keeps giving me an error

```
‘’’
headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req=Request(target, headers)
resp=urllib.request.urlopen({target}, 
bytes(json.dumps(headers),
encoding="utf-8"))
‘’’
```

Returns the error:
AttributeError: ‘set’ object has no attribute ‘data’

Comment: This seems to be only partly Python code. Format this more clearly and show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: `urllib.request.urlopen({target},` In this function call, `{target}` is a set.  Why are you passing a set as the first argument?